# New dependency causing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception

Tags: scala, spray, nosuchmethoderror

I'm working on a project that is making use of a Scala ETCD client (https://github.com/nikore/scala-etcd), this has been all fine and good until I added a Scala Fleet client (https://github.com/MonsantoCo/fleet-client) into the mix.

When I compile it is fine but once I run the project it throws the following exception on the lines where the ETCDClient is constructed

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: spray.json.StandardFormats$class.optionFormat(Lspray/json/StandardFormats;Lspray/json/JsonFormat;)Lspray/json/StandardFormats$OptionFormat;
    at net.nikore.etcd.EtcdJsonProtocol$.optionFormat(EtcdJsonProtocol.scala:5)
    at net.nikore.etcd.EtcdJsonProtocol$.<init>(EtcdJsonProtocol.scala:18)
    at net.nikore.etcd.EtcdJsonProtocol$.<clinit>(EtcdJsonProtocol.scala)
    at net.nikore.etcd.EtcdClient.<init>(EtcdClient.scala:76)
    at net.nikore.etcd.EtcdClient$.apply(EtcdClient.scala:20)
    at au.com.someproject.helpers.SomeProjectService$class.main(SomeProjectService.scala:116)
    at au.com.someproject.some_agent.ServiceMain$.main(ServiceMain.scala:17)
    at au.com.someproject.some_agent.ServiceMain.main(ServiceMain.scala)
```

The only thing that I call tell that might be causing this is that the ETCD Client requires `spray-json 1.3.1` but the Fleet Client requires `spray-json 1.3.2`. Having a look at the compiled package, `spray-json 1.3.2` is packaged.

What is the cause of this (if I am wrong about the dependencies) and how can I go about resolving this?

**EDIT:**

Bellow is the code at `SomeProjectService.scala:116`:

```
etcdClient = EtcdClient(s"http://${serviceConfiguration.getString("someproject.etcd.host")}:${serviceConfiguration.getString("someproject.etcd.port")}")
```

And bellow is the code at `ServiceMain.scala:17`:

```
object ServiceMain extends SomeProjectService {
```

`ServiceMain` is the entry point for the service but the `main` function is declared in the `SomeProjectService` trait where the `etcdClient` is declared

Comment: Well... looks like a problem in your code. Where is the code?

Comment: @sarvesh-kumar-singh I have edited the question to add the line of code in my project that are in question